# Vehicle routing using Google Maps api

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Currently I am developing a piece of software that solves vehicle routing problem using **Google Maps Javascript API v3**.

The task is the following:

- I have several vehicles along the town
- I have lots of destination points along the town
- The number of destination points is greater than the number of available vehicles
- I need to calculate optimal routes through multiple points for every vehicle to minimize the average transportation time

My naive approach is the following:

- find nearest points for each vehicle using k-means clustering with the raw euclidean distance between map points (LngLat points)
- for each vehicle for each destination point from the set of vehicle's nearest destination points calculate optimal routes using other destination points as intermediate points and using `optimize:true` option and find routes with smallest average transportation time

It seems that this approach may give results which are not optimal.

Is there better approach which provides better accuracy and/or smaller amount of API requests.

Comment: Probably you should look into a different API like https://www.graphhopper.com/ (note, I'm one of the authors)